# No brightness control and /sys/class/backlight empty in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: brightness, backlight, wayland

No brightness control available in Ubuntu. I tried various kernel boot paramters and none worked. I tried adding /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel file with intel_backlight - did not work. I have no clue what is gone wrong. This is the case with Ubuntu 17.10 also.

I am using a plane dell keyboard without any backlight illumination. But, I found these values. No video card details are there. But, numlock, caps lock, scroll lock brightness values? I'm confused?

```
sudo find /sys/ -type f -iname '*brightness*'
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:413C:2107.0001/input/input5/input5::capslock/brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:413C:2107.0001/input/input5/input5::capslock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:413C:2107.0001/input/input5/input5::scrolllock/brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:413C:2107.0001/input/input5/input5::scrolllock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:413C:2107.0001/input/input5/input5::numlock/brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:413C:2107.0001/input/input5/input5::numlock/max_brightness
/sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled
/sys/module/i915/parameters/invert_brightness
```

Comment: Maybe try Gnome instead of Wayland and see if it works.

Comment: I'm using Gnome with wayland. Gnome with Xorg also results in the same empty backlight directory.

Comment: Yes I meant to say Xorg. Can we get your machine, CPU, etc. specs?

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
 Memory at fe000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
 Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
 I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
 [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: i915

Comment: And, it is a desktop computer with Intel DH67CL mainboard.

Comment: Desktops don't have hardware brightness controller usually. Xrandr is typical solution.

Comment: xrandr is not working with wayland, unfortunately. The alternate is apps like "brightnessctl" which also is not working.

Comment: I'm working on a project now to adjust brightness and gamma based on internet sunrise and sunset time for user city. It uses xrandr plus laptop hardware. I haven't booted Wayland yet so don't know what xrandr equivalents exist there.

Comment: For the time being, I'm using monitor's brightness control.  :)

Comment: Which is why monitors have brightness control. Laptop monitors however have no brightness controls. Which is why my current project uses: `bash -c "echo $IntBrightness | sudo tee $backlight" > /dev/null`